# Software for drawing two-variable functions in polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am in difficulty of finding a software for drawing two-variable functions in polar coordinates.
Could someone introduce useful software for me? Thanks in advance. 
For example
$$
f(r, \theta)=\begin{cases}
r\cos(\theta+\ln r)& r>0,\\
0& r=0,
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Can you post an actual example?

Comment: @Amzoti : I have just posted my function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine that any [*CAS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) would be able to do it.

- It looks like MatLab has a [*3d-polar-plotting*](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/11/11/3d-polar-plotting/)
- It looks like the free SAGE has [*3d-polar-plot*](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/758/3d-polar-plot)
- I tried your function using Mathematica's SphericalPlot3D command.

Here are two views of this function for both variables over $(0, 2 \pi)$ and the third over $(0, 4 \pi)$..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is changing which parameter is plotted first.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: awesome graphs! +1

Comment: @blindman: You are very welcome. Regards